# Magento 2 How to add a field in estimate shipping section in cart page and estimate shipping based on its selected value?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I want to add a dropdown in estimated shipping section in cart page. It will have some area codes. When user changes its value, then shipping cost should be estimated again based on its value.